# If statement not returning anything inside of two for loops

Tags: javascript, if-statement, return

I'm trying to return an array inside of an if statement, but nothing is returning. When I console.log( [ i, j ] ), it works fine.

```
const twoSum = function(nums, target) {
   for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
       for (let j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
           if (nums[i] + nums[j] === target) {
               return [ i, j ];
           }
       }
   }
};

twoSum([ 2, 7, 11, 15 ], 9);
```

I understand that this is not the most efficient way to solve this problem, but I'm just learning the basics and I'm very confused as to why this is not returning anything.

Comment: You're not doing anything with the return value of your call to `twoSum`. Did you try, `console.log(twoSum([2,7,11,15], 9))`?

Comment: It is working fine.

Comment: you need to output it in the page using id or class selector. try to debug it using `document.write(twoSum([ 2, 7, 11, 15 ], 9));` just to show the results on the page, if the results is there, then it works fine, it's just not bent to any selector yet.

Comment: try with console.log(functioncall)

Answer (score 0):

It should return `[0, 1]`.
If you want to display the result in the console, try:

```
console.log(twoSum([ 2, 7, 11, 15 ], 9));
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can write it this way so it easier to read. having two for loops is difficult to handle. We can optimize this if we know that the array only have positive numbers.

```
  const twoSum = (nums, target) => {
    let found = null;

    nums.some((n, i) => {
      // here you figure where you are looking for.
      const lookingFor = target - n;

      const idx = nums.indexOf(lookingFor, i);

      if (idx !== -1) {
        found = [i, idx];
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });

    return found;
  };

  console.log(twoSum([ 2, 7, 11, 15 ], 9));
```